# How can I retrieve the value of `__all__`

Tags: python, django

In [`django/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py) there's variable:

```
__all__ = [
    'AutoField', 'BLANK_CHOICE_DASH', 'BigAutoField', 'BigIntegerField',
    'BinaryField', 'BooleanField', 'CharField', 'CommaSeparatedIntegerField',
    'DateField', 'DateTimeField', 'DecimalField', 'DurationField',
    'EmailField', 'Empty', 'Field', 'FieldDoesNotExist', 'FilePathField',
    'FloatField', 'GenericIPAddressField', 'IPAddressField', 'IntegerField',
    'NOT_PROVIDED', 'NullBooleanField', 'PositiveIntegerField',
    'PositiveSmallIntegerField', 'SlugField', 'SmallIntegerField', 'TextField',
    'TimeField', 'URLField', 'UUIDField',
]
```

How Django retrieves the variable `__all__`? Is it 
`fields.__init__.__all__` or `fields.__all__`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django does not directly use that variable but it is used by Python `import` statement. You can do the following if you want to access the value:

```
from django.db.models import fields
print(fields.__all__)
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python) for an explanation.